# Why is ØMQ send fails on the 2nd call?

Tags: java

I am using the ØMQ Java client library: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq
I wrote a simple test class that attempts to send two messages:

```
ZContext context = new ZContext();
ZMQ.Socket socket = context.createSocket(SocketType.REQ);
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

socket.send("Message 1".getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET), 0);
System.out.println("Message 1 sent");
socket.send("Message 2".getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET), 0);
System.out.println("Message 2 sent");
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
Message 1 sent
Exception in thread "main" org.zeromq.ZMQException: Errno 156384763 : Operation cannot be accomplished in current state
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.mayRaise(ZMQ.java:3533)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.send(ZMQ.java:3196)
```

Any idea what is causing the error to be triggered when the 2nd message is sent?

Thanks

Comment: I did notice that if I recreate the socket between the first send and the second one, I don't get the error. However, I feel that something is wrong and that I should not have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

It turns out that the sender cannot proceed to send the next message until the receiver will respond to that message...